Help identifying a movie (or en episode), I only remember the end, possibly from the 90's
In the end of the movie a man is in an empty room of an empty house (no furniture, paintings), he opens a little trap door in the middle of floor of the room he is in, he enters the trap door, he closes it, and then closing credits.
It's a trapdoor just like this one:

I really didn't watch the movie, but that ending has stuck with me all those years (five or more).
The man seemed a little depressed.
Sorry but I don't have no more info. Can you tell me what movie or TV-show this is?

This sounds like the The Door in the Floor from 2004. It's loosely based an a novel by John Irving. The film is about a children's author whose sons were killed in an automobile crash. The final scene of the film is the main character looking sadly at the camera and then opening and entering a door in the floor as described.
